# gulp-less on gulp v4

Tags: css, gulp, less, gulp-less

I have updated gulp to v4, and by documentation, gulp-less should only work on gulp version 3.x. When I run the task, styles compile and I get no errors. Why does it require 3.x version, and what can go wrong when using gulp v4? Are there any alternatives to gulp-less?

I tried combining webpack and gulp, to use "less-loader" package, but had no success.